# Changing 4 columns in only 1

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-columns, melt

I am trying to convert 4 colunms from my DataFrame to a unique column.

I have the following DataFrame:

```
    doggo   floofer pupper  puppo
0   None    None    None    None
1   None    None    None    None
2   None    None    None    None
3   None    None    None    None
4   None    None    None    None
5   None    None    None    None
6   None    None    None    None
7   None    None    None    None
8   None    None    None    None
9   doggo   None    None    None
10  None    None    None    None
11  None    None    None    None
12  None    None    None    puppo
13  None    None    None    None
14  None    None    None    puppo
```

I want a unique column filled with the values 'None', 'doggo', 'floofer', 'pupper', 'puppo'.

I have tried using the Melt function with no success.

my actual code:

```
melt = pd.melt(melt, id_vars=['doggo', 'floofer', 'pupper', 'puppo'], var_name='classification')
```

Any help?

**EDIT**

Below the complete solution(comments are in portuguese):

```
#criar uma cópia do DataFrame para não comprometer o DataFrame original
df = twitter_archive.copy()

#Apagar os valores None 
df = df.replace('None', '')

#criar e preencher a coluna classification com as informações das colunas doggo, floofer, pupper e puppo
df['classification'] = (df['doggo'].fillna('') + df['floofer'].fillna('') + df['pupper'].fillna('') + df['puppo'].fillna('')).replace('', np.nan)

#Dropar todas as colunas e deixar somente a classification
df = df.drop(columns=['in_reply_to_status_id', 'in_reply_to_user_id', 'timestamp', 'source', 'text', 'retweeted_status_id', 'retweeted_status_user_id', 'retweeted_status_timestamp', 'expanded_urls', 'rating_numerator', 'rating_denominator', 'name', 'doggo','floofer', 'pupper', 'puppo'])

#Acrescentar a coluna classification no DataFrame twitter_archive e remover as colunas doggo, floofer, pupper e puppo
twitter_archive = pd.merge(twitter_archive, df, on= 'tweet_id')
twitter_archive = twitter_archive.drop(columns=['doggo', 'floofer', 'pupper', 'puppo'])
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way to do it :

```py
df['classification'] = (df['doggo'].fillna('') + df['floofer'].fillna('') + df['pupper'].fillna('') + df['puppo'].fillna('')).replace('', np.nan)
```

Comment: It helped, but still didnt get there. each line has 4 values now... like NoneNoneNoneNone or doggoNoneNoneNone

Comment: I will accept your answer because it helped me to achieve my objective... I will edit my post with the entire solution. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! 
My code would work only if you the 'None' you had in your original dataframe were   `np.nan` and not strings with "None" value. You can drop `.fillna('')` from each column if you don't mind doing it for the entire dataframe (i.e. `df = df.replace('None', '')` ).

Answer (score 0):

just make take the maximum. Every string is larger than None. Assuming your entries(per line) are unique. The following should work

```
d = {"col1": [None, "x", None], "col2": ["y",None, None]}
x = pd.DataFrame(d)
x["col3"] = x[["col1", "col2"]].max(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0  None     y     y
1     x  None     x
2  None  None  None
```